# How to avoid a double click to submit when i entered the data's are valid in jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am attempting to validate a form field remotely. If the field receives focus while I'm on the page, everything works great. However, if the field never receives focus, the form requires I click the "Submit" button twice in order to successfully submit.

I'd like it to either only validate if the field receives focus or somehow stop the form from requiring two clicks to submit. Anyone have any ideas?

This is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
 $j.validator.addMethod("regx", function(value, element, regexpr) {          
    return regexpr.test(value);
}, "Password must contain one lower case letter,upper case letter,digit and special character ex:aaEs#s1@.");
   $j(document).ready(function () {
    $j("#forms").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required",
            principal_name: "required",
            email:
            {
              required: true,
              email: true
             },
            phone_number:
            {
              required: true,
              digits: true,
               minlength:10
            },
            subscription_type:"required",
            username:
            {
             required: true,
             remote: "includes/username_exist.php"
            },
            password: {
             required: true,
             minlength: 8,
             maxlength: 40,
                //regx: /^(?=.*[d])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).{4,8}$/ 
             regx: /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{5,20}$/ 
            },
            confirmPassword: {
                required: true,
                equalTo: "#password"
            },
            logo:
            {
             accept: "jpg|jpeg|png"
            },

        },
        messages: {
            name: "Please enter a name.",
            principal_name: "Please enter a principal name.",
            email:{
             required: "Please enter a Email.",
             email:"Please enter valid email"
             },
             phone_number:{
             required:"Please enter a phone number.",
             digits:"Please enter digits only",
             minlength:"Please enter valid phone number"
              },
             username:
             {
             required:"Please enter a username.",
             remote: jQuery.format("{0} is already in use")
             },
             password:{
             required:"Please enter a password",
             minlength:"Password  must be 5-20 characters",
             maxlength:"Password  must be 5-20 characters"
             },
             confirmPassword:{
             required:"Please enter a confirm password",
             minlength:"Password length must be 5-20 characters",
             maxlength:"Password length must be 5-20 characters",
             equalTo:"Password is mis-match"
             },
             logo:
             {
               accept: 'Not an image!'
             },
            errorContainer: $j('#errorContainer'),
            errorLabelContainer: $j('#errorContainer ul'),
            wrapper: 'li'

        },
        onkeyup: false, //turn off auto validate whilst typing
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert('is good');
            form.submit();
            return true;
        }
    });

});
  </script>

<form class="form-horizontal form-signin-signup" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" id="forms" autocomplete="off">
                  <label for="name" class="signin-form-label">Institution Name<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Institution Name">
                  <label for="principal_name" class="signin-form-label">Principal Name<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="principal_name" placeholder="Principal Name">
                  <label for="email" class="signin-form-label">Email<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
                  <label for="phone_number" class="signin-form-label">Phone Number<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="phone_number" placeholder="Phone Number">


                  <label for="username" class="signin-form-label">Username<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                  <label for="password" class="signin-form-label">Password<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="password" name="password" id ="password"placeholder="Password">
                  <label for="confirm_password" class="signin-form-label">Confirm Password<span>*</span></label>
                  <input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                  <br>
                  <label for="name" class="signin-form-label">Logo Upload</label>
                  <div class="logo_center">
                  <div class="logo_left">
                  <input type="file" name="logo">
                  </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="remember-me">
                    <div class="pull-left">
                     <div class="send_mail">
                     <label class="checkbox">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="mail_notify" value="1"> Send Email Notifications
                      </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="Create Institution" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">
                  </div>
                </form>
```

Thanks & Regards.

Comment: So where is the HTML markup for the form?

Comment: Hi sparky. I had included the HTML markup for the form.

Comment: I had fixed the issue.

Comment: Besides what I pointed out in my answer, what was the issue? This site is about helping others in the future by providing clearly written questions and answers.  In other words, either "accept" my posted answer, or post the correct answer yourself and accept that.  Since you added your HTML, your question was re-opened to allow new answers.  Thanks.

Comment: By adding async:false in remote: {url:"check.php", async:false} the issue was resolved

Answer (score 0):

Once you properly format the code (indentation, line-breaks, etc), the problem becomes obvious.  You've incorrectly placed the `errorContainer`, `errorLabelContainer`, and `wrapper` options inside of the `messages` option.  These options are all supposed to be siblings.

```
$j("#forms").validate({
    rules: {
         // your rules,  
         logo: {
             accept: "jpg|jpeg|png"
         },
     },
     messages: {
        // your messages,  
        logo: {
            accept: 'Not an image!'
        },
        errorContainer: $j('#errorContainer'),  // <-- does not belong inside 'messages' option
        errorLabelContainer: $j('#errorContainer ul'),  // <-- does not belong inside 'messages' option
        wrapper: 'li'  // <-- does not belong inside 'messages' option
    },
    onkeyup: false, //turn off auto validate whilst typing
    submitHandler: function (form) {...}
});
```

You're also using the `accept` method wrong if you're trying to match the file extension.

- [`accept` is for mimetype](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/)
- [`extension` is for file extensions](http://jqueryvalidation.org/extension-method/)

And [you don't need to wrap your target selectors with jQuery](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)...

Should be more like this...

```
$j("#forms").validate({
    rules: {
         // your rules,  
         logo: {
             extension: "jpg|jpeg|png"
         }  // <-- removed sloppy trailing comma
     },
     messages: {
        // your messages,  
        logo: {
            extension: 'Not an image!'
        }
    },
    errorContainer: '#errorContainer',         // <-- no need to wrap with $j()
    errorLabelContainer: '#errorContainer ul', // <-- no need to wrap with $j()
    wrapper: 'li',
    onkeyup: false, //turn off auto validate whilst typing
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('is good');
        /*_____________________________________________________________
        the entire 'submitHandler' is not needed if the 
        only code is 'form.submit()', because this is the default 
        _____________________________________________________________*/
        form.submit();
        // return true;  // <-- unnecessary & superfluous
    }
});
```